# Generate a TXT file from variables with a PHP file : can't add new lines?

Tags: php, json, graph, newline

I wrote a small code in PHP in order to parse variables.
I would like each time this code is called, a new line is added in the TXT file.

Each line will contain a time stamp , ie : 09:30 and a temperature value
Once the TXT file is filled-in i would like to generate a Google Chart.

Time Stamps are going to be Abcisses (X) and corresponding temp value will be Y

So far, a new line is NOT created in the TXT file.
Would you please help me to find out why ?

```html
 <?
 $File = 'live_datas.txt';
 
 # GRAB THE VARIABLES FROM THE URL
 $HeuresTronconMesure = $_GET['hour'];
 $MinutesTronconMesure = $_GET['min'];
 $DonneeCapteur = $_GET['data'];

 # --------------------------------

  $FICHIER = fopen($File, "w");
 
 # Generate Timestamp : HH:MM
 fputs($FICHIER, $HeuresTronconMesure);
 fputs($FICHIER , ":");
 fputs($FICHIER, $MinutesTronconMesure);
  
 # Add 1 space
 fputs($FICHIER , " ");

 # Add Temperature Value
 fputs($FICHIER, $DonneeCapteur);
 
 # Add a new line
 fputs ($FICHIER , "\r\n");
  
 # Close the file
 fclose($FICHIER);  
 ?>
```

At the end, i expect to get "live_datas.txt" with something like :

```html
04:50 25.29
05:00 24.30
07:30 25.20
08:45 26.00
10:15 27.50
```

Regards,

Comment: What is the actual output that you're getting? Is it just the last line, or nothing at all?

Answer (score 2):

You have to open your file in append mode:

```
$FICHIER = fopen($File, "a");
```

What manual says about both modes:

> "w" (Write only. Opens and clears the contents of file; or creates a new file if it doesn't exist)
>
> "a" (Write only. Opens and writes to the end of the file or creates a new file if it doesn't exist)

Comment: Edit : Many thanks Patricio, now it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad it worked. Mark this answer as a solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//call function
writeData($_GET['hour'], $_GET['min'], $_GET['data']);

//function definition
function writeData($hour, $min, $temperature) {
  $path = 'live_datas.txt';
  $line = "{$hour}:{$min} {$temperature}\r\n";
  if (file_exists($path)) {
    file_put_contents($path, $line, FILE_APPEND);
  }
  else {
    file_put_contents($path, $line);
  }
}
```